# Alterar controllers gerados por scaffold C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Bom pessoal, estava estudando sobre Entity Framework e vi que existe a ferramenta scaffolding que gera um CRUD completo com controllers e views.

A minha duvida é que se eu posso alterar a logica das actions ou estruturas criadas livremente ou isso não é recomendado?

Ps: Não digo alterar todas as actions/estruturas criadas, mas coisas pontuais como por exemplo ao inserir um dado em uma tabela, a action deve criar um registro em outra tabela de quem adicionou tal dado e quando.

desde já agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: Eu diria que deve e muito...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, você pode e deve. 
Cada aplicação tem suas particularidades, o que o framework gera é muito genérico, adapte-o as suas necessidades.

Comment: Muito obrigado!